# how to take specific column from text file(.txt) with delimiters with C#

Tags: c#, text-files

I have example data like this , the data is in the text file(.txt) sry i got this type of file, if its excel or csv maybe it will be easier

Edit : i make a console app with C#

```
FamilyID;name;gender;DOB;Place of birth;status
1;nicky;male;01-01-1998;greenland;married
1;sonia;female;02-02-1995;greenland;married
2;dicky;male;04-01-1995;bali;single
3;redding;male;01-05-1996;USA;single
3;sisca;female;05-03-1994;australia;married
```

i want to take the specific column from that data, for example i want to take FamilyID,Name and status.

I already tried some code to read data and take all the data and list it to new text file.

The goal is to create a new text file based on family ID, and only take specific columns.

The problem is : i cant take a specific column that i want from text file (don't know how to select many column in the code that i write)

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string tgl = date.Date.ToString("dd");
            string bln = date.Month.ToString("d2");
            string thn = date.Year.ToString();
            string tglskrg = thn + "/" + bln + "/" + tgl;

            string filename = ("C:\\Users\\Documents\\My Received Files\\exampledata.txt");
            string[] liness = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
            string[] col;

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);


            var groups = lines.Skip(1)
                  .Select(x => x.Split(';')) 
                  .GroupBy(x => x[0]).ToArray();


            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(group);
                File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\Documents\\My Received Files\\exampledata_"+group.Key+".txt", group.Select(x => string.Join(";", x)));
}
```

maybe someone can help? thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be capture the details to a data structure and later write the required details to file. For example,

```
public class Detail
{
    public int FamilyID{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Gender{get;set;}
    public DateTime DOB{get;set;}
    public string PlaceOfBirth{get;set;}
    public string Status{get;set;}
}
```

Now you can write a method that parses the string based on delimiter and returns an IEnumerable.

```
public IEnumerable<Detail> Parse(string source,char delimiter)
{
    return source.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Skip(1)
          .Select(x=> 
          {
            var detail = x.Split(new []{delimiter});
            return new Detail
            {
                FamilyID = Int32.Parse(detail[0]),
                Name = detail[1],
                Gender = detail[2],
                DOB = DateTime.Parse(detail[3]),
                PlaceOfBirth = detail[4],
                Status = detail[5]
            };
          }
          );

}
```

Client Call

```
Parse(stringFromFile,';');
```

Output

[image]

Now you can pick and write the details you want to write to output file from the collection.

Comment: hmm is it apply able for console app?

Comment: You can use it irrespective of  console/winform/wpf/web. Please note the Image attached is a represntation of output. You can use Console application to output the collection or write to a file

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var list = new List<String>();
        list.Add("FamilyID;name;gender;DOB;Place of birth;status");
        list.Add("1;nicky;male;01-01-1998;greenland;married");
        list.Add("1;sonia;female;02-02-1995;greenland;married");
        list.Add("2;dicky;male;04-01-1995;bali;single");
        list.Add("3;redding;male;01-05-1996;USA;single");
        list.Add("3;sisca;female;05-03-1994;australia;married");

        var group = from item in list.Skip(1)
                    let splitItem = item.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    select new
                    {
                        FamilyID = splitItem[0],
                        Name = splitItem[1],
                        Status = splitItem[5],
                    };

        foreach(var item in group.ToList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Family ID: {item.FamilyID}, Name: {item.Name}, Status: {item.Status}");
        }
```